# jQuery Sortable With Cookies

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to have a 4 div widget page that you can drag and drop to change the layout. I have two things that I cant figure out. One, I would like to save the layout and load the layout from the jQuery cookie plugin but cant figure out how. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/savagenoob/AUjN6/)

It might fix itself when I put more data in the div's, but when I drag the items, would like them to swap places with the ending element, right now it just adds to it.

I think this is how you set the cookie:

```
 update:function(e,ui) {
        var order = foo.sortable("toArray").join();
        $.cookie("sortableOrder",order);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, is during the page load, check the cookie for a value. If it has it, the loop through the cookie values, and compare to element s currently in the list. If it exist, add the item from the cookie to a new list. The newly built list is then what you append to the page, and remove the original list, in that sense, loading the saved order of items.  So, essentially you have three arrays. 1. The actual list of items in the page during load time. 2. The list stored in the cookie. 3. An empty list at load time, that you will use to build your newly ordered list. When you compare the current list to the list items in the cookie, and they exist in both, you place that element in the third "previously" empty array.  That way when you have looped through all items, you have your new ordered list, and remove the original.

Hopefully this helps. I would further explain with example, but at work. Sorry.. :(